# Pass data within an Iframe form and track it with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am facing a challenging task and I need some insights about it.

I have the main domain : **domain.com**

And an Iframe inside this domain pages : **iframe.com**

The users path :

1. Users come on **domain.com**
2. Users visits some pages and the initiates the form inside **iframe.com**
3. Process goes through some pages inside the iframe until the form validation on **iframe.com/form-sent**
4. During all the form process, the **domain.com** page path is not changing

On on side, I am tracking referrers landing on **domain.com**.

On another, I can track the form process on **iframe.com**.

I want to create a goal for a **form completed by a specific referrer**, thus passing a variable from **domain.com** to **iframe.com**.

But the data I retrieve on **domain.com** cannot be read by **iframe.com**.

Is there a method to do that ?

Notes: I set up cross-domain tracking with GTM.

The Html page and the iframe are on a seperate domain... so I am facing the error

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin

And the **domain.com** is "http" as the **iframe.com** is https.

Not sure if I can get it around !

Comment: as long as you have cross-domain tracking in place you don't need to pass any variable to an iframe. you may set up the goal for iframe.com/form-sent and that goal would have the traffic source referred to domain.com.

Comment: Alright... so maybe my cross-domain tracking as flaws... I have 2 different tracking ID for each domain.. maybe that's a wrong thing to do.

Comment: yes, you need the same tracking ID on both sites and you have to add both domains to referral exclusions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use postMessages to send information from the iframe to the website.

Inside the iframe you need to send a postMessage and, on your website, you need to create a listener. Once the postMessage is received by your domain, you can use the data you get from it to send an event to Google Analytics and then create a Goal.

To learn how to use postMessages I recommend you to read the documentation from MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Thanks it seems nice.. however it requires to modifiy the html on the iframe and I have currently no access to it (remote proprietary platform).
I'll look for an alternative method.

Comment: After a try, i am facing the cross-domain iframes block becaus the iframe is from another domain... and the main domain is "http" as iframe domain is "https" !  Not sure I can go around these limitations ((